# Can someone tell me why this code is going infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, infinite-loop

> it is supposed to increment every other element in an array but when I run it it goes to infinite loop.

```
function incrementSecond(arr){
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i + 2){
  arr[i] += 1;
  console.log(arr[i]);
 }
 return arr;
};
console.log(incrementSecond([1,2,3,4]));
```

Comment: `i + 2` is just adding 2 to the current value of `i`. Its not assigning the result of addition to `i`. You could use `i += 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) {
```

Change `i + 2` to `i = i + 2` or `i += 2`.

Comment: Good catch. By quick reading the code I didn't even notice it . I thought it was `i+=2`

Comment: thank you so much! this fixed it!